# Net Core request model changes decimal values

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

When sending a request model to Net Core API from Angular app, it changes the floating point variable's value.

Here is the request body sent from Angular app.

[image: Angular]

And when it hits the net core api it changes to this.

[image: Net Core]

The problem can be fixed by rounding in this case but I wonder if it will have harming affects with other values.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: I couldn't fix it mate and was never able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like `Quantity` has `double` type. Change it to `decimal` in order to precisely represent decimal values.